# Android SDK download fails

Tags: android

I can't download the Android SDK for OSX from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

The download gets interrupted after 10%, I tried to download it with different browsers and on different machines (Windows and Mac) so I guess that there is a problem on the server.

Is there an mirror for the OSX SDK or can the link be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: Download runs perfectly fine here. Maybe you should reconnect to your internet. Best wishes,
Tim

Comment: are you behind any proxy ? if so , then contact your network administrator, otherwise try deleting your internet temporary files and try again

Comment: you can assume the Google servers are not the problem. It may be that your machine is (because of your ISP) going through to many nodes and there is some timeout occurring along the way. Get a friend to download it and then put it in a dropbox share for you (or similar). Also this isn't really a StackOver flow question (its not programming related). You should probably post it to the  [Android StackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/?as=1)

Comment: Instructions for offline download here - http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html